# Laravel 4 - 403 Permissions error when trying to access css/js files

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, apache2, http-status-code-403

I'm running on an Ubuntu 13.10 dev environment with Apache2 and after hours of trying to figure out permission errors to access routes, I was able to fix it. Now I can successfully browse through my application, but the problem that now exists is that I cannot access my css/js files within my public directory - it kicks back with a 403.

I've tried modifying the .htaccess file, the virtual host config file, and ran chmod on the entire site directory.

Here's a copy of my .htaccess file within the Public folder:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

And here's a copy of my virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/home/casey/Sites/caseyhoffmann.me/public"
ServerName caseyhoffmann.me.dev
<Directory "/home/casey/Sites/caseyhoffmann.me/public/">
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Solved. Reapplied chown and redid chmod on the directory. File system permissions issue and had nothing to do with Apache.

Comment: If you notice what were the correct permissions, it will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1: (Recommended)**

use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

**Solution 2:**

You can try adding this in your page's header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: I'm using Laravel's HTML helper class which outputs the absolute path: HTML::style('css/bootstrap-flatly.min.css')   This translates into this: <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/css/bootstrap-flatly.min.css">  in the source.

Comment: In that case css URL won't be impacted since you have `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` in your rule.

Comment: So you're saying that I shouldn't use that? I'm a bit confused.